# Save and return

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm curious about the definition of a User - is that anyone who fills out our form, or does it just refer to someone with login access to our account?

For example - we'd like to use Cognito forms for our dog adoption application. We'd like potential adopters to be able to save the form and return to it later to complete it, since they may need to collect information such as vet references etc.

Would that functionality be possible with the Pro plan?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely!

[Users](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/multiple-users-organizations) for Cognito Forms are people who actually log in to build forms and manage entries, and starting with the Pro plan you can have multiple users.  However, there is no limit on the number of customers you can have submitting forms, outside of generous monthly submission limits.

Starting with the [Pro plan](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing), you can enable [Save & Resume](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/save-resume) to allow your customers to starting filling out their application and save their progress so they can pick up later.  This plan also supports [sharing submitted entries](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/entry-sharing), so you send forms back to your customers for additional information after they have submitted them to you.